# Which mantras should be chanted for Agnihotra more than aahuti?

Tags: rituals, mantras, sacrifice

I perform it daily and I know about
SaptaShloki , sunrise and sunset mantras but I wish to chant more and different shlokas like mantras, Vedic Shlokas and Vedic Sukta. Can I ?
**Can I chant Purush Sukta/ Agni sukta or other sukta?**

[image: Agnihotra]

Comment: You can chant whichever Mantra you want to. But please be aware of when and how to chant them.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, you cannot just chant whichever Mantra you want to. But, if you are qualified to learn it from a guru, then you should be aware of when and how to chant them.

Comment: @ram Read the next line.

Answer (score 2):

There are no complicated mantras involved in the process of agnihotra.

However timing is of key importance. There are [apps](http://www.agnihotra.org/mantras/) which notify you for exact time sun rise and sunset. During which the ahutis are of maximum potency.

The core ritual revolves around ahutis for surya agni and prajApati.

You can do a simplified process by offering oblations with following mantras

**Sunrise Agnihotra mantra**

Sooryaya swaha | sooryaya idam na mama

Prajapataye swaha | prajapataye idam na mama

**Sunset Agnihotra mantra**

Agnaye swaha |agnaye idam na mama

Prajapataye swaha | prajapataye idam na mama

So these four are the main mantras to be used. If you want to do something more then you can use gayatri mantra or trayambaka mantras etc.

There is no restrictions for adding more vedic mantras after the main ahutis are done.

Comment: Guide me about suktas

Comment: @YOGANAND, where in India are you located ? Suggest you go to a nearby veda-patashala instead of asking on internet.

Comment: @ram  thats a good idea.

Comment: @YOGANAND initially do with whatever mantras you are already knowing. If you want to learn new mantras then yes you need to approach a genuine veda paathi or gurukul.

Answer (score 0):

It seems one can chant other mantras such as om triambakam mantra, during agnihotra, except during main ahuti time.  See more info here: https://www.agnihotra.com.au/homas-mantras/